# Errors in the C code

Tags: c

I have written the following code for my project. The code is scattered across various files and quite long so i am posting the minimal code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
struct TwoPoint
{
    int width;
    int value;
};

struct Module 
{
    int categ;
    void *ptr;
};

struct Rect
{
    struct TwoPoint val;
    struct TwoPoint val_new;
    bool is_changed;
};

struct S
{
    int numInstances;
    struct Module instances[20];
    struct Rect RectList[40];
    int numRect;
}s1;

struct Test
{
    int categ;
    struct Rect state;
};

struct TwoPoint initPVal(int v,int w)
{
struct TwoPoint temp;
temp.value=v;
temp.width=w;
return temp;
}
int getValue(struct TwoPoint *b)
{
    return (b->value);
}

struct TwoPoint get(struct Rect *r)
{
    return (r->val);
}

void initialize()
{
     s1.numInstances=0;
     s1.numRect=0;
}

void addRect(struct Rect *r)
{
     if(s1.numRect<40)
     {
     s1.RectList[s1.numRect].val=r->val;
     s1.RectList[s1.numRect].val_new=r->val_new;
     s1.RectList[s1.numRect].is_changed=r->is_changed;
     s1.numRect++;
     }
}

struct Rect initRect(struct TwoPoint initval) 
{
struct Rect temp;
struct TwoPoint tempP;
tempP=initPVal(0,0);
temp.val=initval;
temp.val_new=tempP;
temp.is_changed=false;
addRect(&temp);
return temp;
}

void copy(struct Rect *r)
{
    if(r->is_changed)
    {
    r->val= r->val_new;
    r->is_changed=false;
    }
}
void copyRect()
{
   int i=0;
   for(i=0;i<s1.numRect;i++)
   {    
    copy(&s1.RectList[i]);
   }
}

void setInstance(struct Module *m)
{
    s1.instances[s1.numInstances].categ=m->categ;
    s1.instances[s1.numInstances].ptr=m->ptr;
    s1.numInstances++;
    if (s1.numInstances >= 20)
    {
    printf("Too many instances");
    }
}

void setModule(struct Test *t)
{
    struct Module m;
    m.categ=t->categ;
    m.ptr=&t;
    setInstance(&m);
}



void init(struct Test *t)
{
    t->categ=2;
    struct Rect tr;
    struct TwoPoint tb1=initPVal(0,5);
    tr=initRect(tb1);
    t->state=tr;
}

void actions(struct Test *t)
{
    struct TwoPoint tb=get(&t->state);
    int y=getValue(&tb);
    printf("%d\n",y);
    unsigned int x=getValue(&tb);
    printf("%u\n",x);
    switch(y)
    {
      ....
    }
}

void initS() 
{   
     init(s1.instances[0].ptr);
}   

void act() 
{       
     actions(s1.instances[0].ptr);
}

void setup()
{
    struct Test t;
    initialize();
    init(&t);
    setModule(&t);
}

void run()
{ 
    initS();
    act();
    copyRect();
}


int main()
{
    printf("foo\n");
    setup();
    printf("bar\n");
    run();
    return 0;
}
```

There are two errors:

1. The init() function when called through initS() function leads to Stack Overdumped error whereas it worked fine while i called it in setup(). I think Call is correct as action() function is being executed.
2. The second problem is in actions() function. When i am calculating the value of y to be used as switch condition instead of the value being 0,1,2 or 3 it is some memory address which i found by printing it while trying to debug.

Comment: You haven't posted any function named `setup()` or `action()` (although I assume there you meant `actions()`).

Comment: Also, copy() and initRect() seem to be missing. BTW what does the compiler say if you set the warning level to maximal ( -Wall, -pedantic for gcc)

Comment: have you checked the obvious things? eg: `s1.instances[0].ptr`

Comment: @yi_H The same call works in act()

Comment: Hint: just for learning start with something smaller; one or two structure types. Initialise them, then print them. Test it. The current snippet is still full of errors, most of them indicating that you don't understand pointers, and you don't understand automatic storage. Don't confuse yourself: start small. Good luck. The good news is: since yesterday the program seems to have improved a bit.

Comment: @Rog Matthews: doesn't matter, have you checked it?

Comment: It did not compile here. Not even after adding stdio.h stdlib.h and stdbool.h and removing the `....` .

Comment: @wildplasser http://codepad.org/SRjsWVX5

Comment: Odd. The code compiles for me and prints out foo bar 0 0.

Comment: It compiles fine with `c99 -Wall` after removing `...`; no warnings. It print `"foo\nbar\n0\n0\n"`.

Comment: Maybe after adding the missing functions. NOTE to the OP: please start with posting a complete but minimal example of your problem. That will avoid a lot of double work for everyone who tries to reconstruct your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
void setup()
{
    struct Test t;
    initialize();
    init(&t);
    setModule(&t);
}
```

A `Test` structure is allocated as a local stack variable and then the address of it assigned to some variable which is accessed later. The next time this variable is accessed is in (`init`):

```
void init(struct Test *t)
{
    t->categ=2;
    struct Rect tr;
    struct TwoPoint tb1=initPVal(0,5);
    tr=initRect(tb1);

    t->state = tr;
}
```

At this point the pointer points to a variable that has fallen out of scope, resulting in undefined behaviour. What actually happens is that the stack gets smashed because of the structure assignment which is attempted. This is why it's also difficult to get a backtrace.

One solution is to allocate the memory with `malloc` like so:

```
void setup()
{
    struct Test * t = malloc(sizeof (struct Test));
    initialize();
    init(t);
    setModule(t);
}
```

Another problem existed, namely a semantic bug in `setModule`:

```
void setModule(struct Test *t)
{
    struct Module m;
    m.categ=t->categ;
    m.ptr=&t;
    setInstance(&m);
}
```

`m.ptr=&t` should actually be `m.ptr = t`. The assignment of a pointer to a `Test` structure was intended. Instead, what happened was that the address of a stack variable holding a pointer to a `Test` structure (double pointer to a `Test` structure) was assigned.

Comment: but when i running it on my computer i am getting errors. i ran the code on codepad, there was error there also.  http://codepad.org/SRjsWVX5

Comment: it still produces the same error in my computer as well as codepad http://codepad.org/dFNo3UF7

Comment: Since you were depending on undefined behaviour, you can't expect it to be consistent. I'm not even sure exactly what you are intending to do with your code. Your best way forward is probably to add lots of debug statements to log variable values and compare them to what **you** are expecting them to be. If after that, you are able to produce a small example exhibiting behaviour you can not understand, we would be able to help you better.

Comment: But this is exactly the example that exhibits the behaviour i want.. it is not some random example but a part of my code(actually most important part of my code)

Comment: Then can you add some comments or write a few sentences explaining what you are expecting the code to do? (In terms of what you think each function is supposed to be doing)

Comment: I have two user defined types which exhibit some common behavior and can have many instances. I want to refer them using a single type. This behavior would have been very easy to implement in OO language(like Java). But in C there are no types that can have member functions. also it does not support inheritance. So i made two structures and different functions with different names. Now module is a structure that contains a void pointer and can point to any of the two. So i won't need inheritance(or interfaces) and can refer to any of the two using single type i.e. module.

Comment: Right. So `Module` is supposed to be able to encapsulate two structures. Which are those? And where are you expecting this assignment to happen? Why does the `Test` structure come into play?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that where you show `run()` calling `actions()`, it is actually calling `act()`, since the former function requires a parameter.

In `setModule()`, you have

```
m.ptr=&t;
```

where `t` is already a pointer to `struct Test`.  So what you have stored in `m.ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to a struct.  In `act()`, you pass this stored pointer to `actions()`, which is expecting a pointer to a struct, not a pointer to a pointer to a struct.  So when the function dereferences the pointer and treats the result as a `struct Test`, it's getting who-knows-what.

Most likely, you want to simply change the line in `setModule()` to

```
m.ptr=t;
```

since `t` is already a pointer.  But perhaps there is some reason you really want to have a pointer to a pointer, in which case you need to change the code that uses the pointer to use it properly.  A problem here is that the compiler can't help you ensure type safety since you're storing the pointer as `void *` and implicitly converting it to other types.

As a side note, you seem to be using the `&` operator a lot more than I think is usual.  It seems to me that your functions that are read-only, e.g. `getValue()`, should simply take a struct parameter, not a pointer to a struct, and then you would not need to obtain the addresses of variables so much.  But perhaps this is a matter of taste.